# Studying electrodynamics problems

Tags: soft-question, electromagnetism, education

Suppose an advanced undergraduate student has reached a moderate level of understanding on electrodynamics.
Where should he **focus** on, to sharpen his **problem-solving skills**?

- Practicing integrals and/or other **mathematical tools**.
- Studying **theoretical results**.
- Working on the **physical meaning** and applications of ED equations.
- Something else.

I understand this is a somewhat subjective question but please try to be as objective as possible: state what really **works** based on your experience as a teacher/TA for example

Comment: To be clear, what are your goals? By "problem solving skills" do you mean "getting As in E&M classes?" Or "doing good research in E&M related stuff?" Or something else entirely?

Comment: @Spencer: to help my students "get better" at solving *undergraduate problems* on electrodynamics. (Problems like those on Griffiths' books for example)

Comment: And are you going for full ED effects (such as solving the wave equation with given boundary and initial conditions) or some application (like electrostatic, circuits, etc.)? Also, are relativity exercises fine? E.g. boosting some solutions and seeing what happens.

Comment: A minimalist answer - work them out on the blackboard during class. There is no substitute.

Comment: @Marek: full ED would be. Some things from radiation *could* be left out. Most relativity problems *probably will* be left out.

Comment: @space_cadet: Off course there is no substitute for that. I'm just looking for something extra and I want that "something extra" to be well thought.

Comment: @Eelvex in this day and age of powerpoint presentations I don't take for granted that this fact is understood by the majority of instructors.

Comment: Is it to be understood that the students you have in mind are fluent with classical vector analysis and its integral theorems? (The classical versions of the general Stoke's theorem?)

Comment: @Tim: practically, the average student is "good" with vector analysis and "ok" on integral theorems.

Comment: Do boundary value problems in a curved space background so they will be ready to do AdS/CFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my humble experience, solving Griffiths problems gets you good at solving Griffiths problems, but not much more. Typically, they've already done/seen the math required, so I'd only work on the calculus part if they're really struggling. Studying theoretical results doesn't seem a great idea either; they'll pick that up along the way or in class. What I prefer is to study more 'extended' problems, i.e. a real life example for the (classical) literature, guide them through the development and finish with a comparison to experimental results. This way, they plough through the maths but also need to do a minimum of interpreting. However, if your goal is just to get them great at working Griffiths-like problems, this might be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to stay in physics, you're going to have to take the physics GRE. So why not study the E&M questions on the sample GRE tests? They're nice simple questions and test your understanding of physics, not your understanding of mathematics. You can get the sample questions here:
http://grephysics.net/ans/

Comment: Using GRE questions is an interesting idea. Note, however, that focusing on mathematical understanding *may* be something we *want* (see question's comments).